# Как правильно указать путь к изображению в Django + HTML

Tags: html, python, django, path, media

**Здравствуйте. Нужно указать путь для изображения в HTML при использовании Django.** 
 Вроде бы звучит не сложно, на деле как я ни пытался, ничего не выходит. 
Мне нужно указать следующий путь к изображению - `"main_page/MCStore logo.png"`. 
Изображение хранится по пути `"media/main_page/MCStore logo.png"`. 
В итоге изображение не выводит, хотя путь прописан правильно. 
Пробовал ставить `"media/main_page/MCStore logo.png"`, тогда на главной странице сайта всё в порядке, работает, но на других пытается вывести по адресу `"news/media/main_page/MCStore logo.png"`. 
Первое слово в пути (в примере указано **news**) меняется в зависимости от url адреса страницы сайта. 
Вопрос в следующем: как мне указать путь, который не будет изменятся. Вариант с P:/... пробовал, не пашет. 
Есть предположение, что дело в settings.py. Вот мои настройки, надеюсь поможет в решении проблемы.
settings.py:

```
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR, ]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'statics'

MEDIA_ROOT = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь. Заранее всем спасибо за активность!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Comment: у меня так раньше было написано, не помогло

Comment: @IIIyTH1K  как у вас вообще может меняться путь к медиа файлом от урл? Если в настройках задано что медиа файлы хранятся в папке медиа

Comment: я как раз это и пытаюсь узнать. Уже недели 2 не могу решить эту проблему. Может быть добавить ещё какие-то данные, который могут помочь с решением задачи. Буду очень благодарен

Comment: @IIIyTH1K из того что вы сейчас скинули это невозможно понять.

Comment: а что я могу скинуть, что бы стало понятнее в чём дело? Просто я уже ума не приложу, не могу никуда двигаться, так как никакие изображения не показываются, даже задний фон поставить не могу. Спасибо, что уделили время!

Comment: @IIIyTH1K если есть возможность скиньтена гитхаб и ссылку сюда

Comment: https://github.com/ItsIIIyTH1K/needahelp.git Загрузил, попробуйте, должно работать) Я новичёк на Гитхабе

Comment: @IIIyTH1K хотелось бы конечно попробовать запустить и смотреть что не так, так пока не вижу проблем. А как вы загружаете файлы и выводите их?

Comment: в каком плане загружаю? Всмысле что в ручную закидываю их в папку?

Comment: @IIIyTH1K в  models.py скиньте строчку где загружаете меди файлы. И как в шаблоне на страницу выводите

Comment: те файлы, что загружатся через модели выводятся нормально. Но особо понимаю что именно вы имеете ввиду. Вот одна из строчек, где используются медиа файлы: image_0 = models.ImageField(upload_to='rigs', null=True, blank=True, default='/default_rig_image.png'), если вы об этом. Эти же изображения вывожу следующим образом: "{{ post.image_0.url }}". Но опять же говорю, эти изображения выводятся нормально, а те, что не находятся в цикле, а выводятся просто как картинки - не отображаются.

Comment: @IIIyTH1K в каком цикле? Т.е у вас не выводятся статические файлы ?

Comment: цикл {% for post in rig %} который выводит блоки с данными (post.title, post.image_0 и т.д.). Они работают, а просто обычные картинки взятые из папки не выводятся. Сама статика подключена, css файлы работают. Опять же я новичёк, возможно что-то упускаю. Могу скинуть скриншоты сайта, если нужно. Спасибо!

Comment: @IIIyTH1K  что-то вы меня запутали) я так понял с фалами которые загружаются в бд из моделей все в порядке. Не отображаются файлы (например как лого сайта) статические ?  такие файлы загружаются в папку со статикой, там же где и стили, чтобы разграничитьт их со стилями и js  файлами внутри папки static создайте папку image. в нее закидывайте все такие файлы.
на страницу выводите так  `<img src="{%static "image/logo.png" %}" class="logo">` в начале шаблона пишите тег `{%load static%}`

Comment: Спасибо, теперь должно работать, но опять почему-то к url пути изображения добавляется url страницы. Вот что пишет, когда пытаешся открыть картинку: rigs/{ static 'image/shopping-cart.png' }. В этом как раз таки была главная проблема. Вот если что настройки static: STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR, ], STATIC_URL = '/static/', STATIC_ROOT = 'statics'. Спасибо)

Comment: @IIIyTH1K попробуйте удалить `urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)`  в urls.py

Comment: всё, работает, спасибо. Я так сам немного накосячил) В итоге удаление static в urlpatterns  и перемещение картинок в другую дерикторию реально помогло решению проблемы! Очень вам благодарен. Не знаю что бы делал. Без вывода изображений не мог реализовать никаких функций. Ещё раз спасибо! P.S У кого такая же проблема, попробуйте сделать то, что и я выше

Comment: @IIIyTH1K рад что помогло) значит не зря тратил время